# CSS 3 corner ribbon

Tags: css, ribbon, css-shapes

I'm trying to change Chris's corner ribbon snippet at http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/H6rQ6/1/. I want the ribbon to be at left instead of right

This is what i have done so far http://jsbin.com/imUQula/1/ the upper part & lower part of ribbon are not changing . I want the upper part flat horizontal & bottom flat vertical

css

```
.wrapper {
margin: 50px auto;
width: 280px;
height: 370px;
background: white;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
position: relative;
z-index: 90;
}

.ribbon-wrapper-green {
width: 85px;
height: 88px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -3px;
left: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);
position: relative;
padding: 7px 0;
left: -5px;
top: 15px;
width: 120px;
background-color: #BFDC7A;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A),   to(#8EBF45)); 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
color: #6a6340;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
content: "";
border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
border-left:  3px solid transparent;
 border-right: 3px solid transparent;
position:absolute;
bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
 right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, do the below changes to your CSS to get it working the way you want:

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 370px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
  overflow: hidden; /* added to hide the part of the green ribbon which goes out of the wrapper */
}
```

[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/UGepAxu/1)

**EDIT:** Actually, the earlier changes that I had mentioned to the `.ribbon-wrapper-green` is not required. You could simply do the below instead.

```
.ribbon-green {
    left: -28px; /* changed from left -5px for the purpose of positioning */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/sudheer105/Fnpn7/

```
.wrapper {
margin: 50px auto;
width: 280px;
height: 370px;
background: white;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
position: relative;
z-index: 90;
}

.ribbon-wrapper-green {
width: 85px;
height: 88px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -3px;
left: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);
position: relative;
padding: 7px 0;
right: 30px;
top: 15px;
width: 120px;
background-color: #BFDC7A;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A),   to(#8EBF45)); 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
color: #6a6340;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
content: "";
border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
border-left:  3px solid transparent;
 border-right: 3px solid transparent;
position:absolute;
bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
right: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
 left: 0;
}
```